# pinesctip - is it possible to make an open, a close or an exit, the bases on which to determine things

Tags: pine-script

What I am keen to understand is, is it possible for pine script to detect that a strategy.exit has occurred and use that to determine other code on. The reason is, that sometimes a trade will exit on the first bar, and its very hard to determine later that there was a trade, because the position size at the close of the bar is 0. I'm thinking that if pinescript could detect an exit, then at least you could figure out there had been a trade.

Comment: I mean, its possible to determine that there's been a trade by querying you trade criteria, but in order to know if the position size was zero when the criteria were met, you have to query position size, and it doesn't know the position after an exit on the first trade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index() and compare it to bar_index. If they are equal then an exit occurred on the current bar. If bar_index is higher by one then an exit occurred last bar etc.

Comment: thankyou, interesting, can you drop me a line of code with that in it? not sure how and where to use that command....